# How to call function in component B when I get an event for this function in Component A

Tags: angular, events, eventemitter

I want to use Event Emiter when I get an event from ws:

I have this function that get me events, When I have an event I want to call a function in other component.

Component A, typescript code:

```
@Output() notify: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
getSocketevent() {
  this.socket.on('data', (data) => {
    this.notify.emit(data)
  });
}
```

Component A, html code:

```
<app-component-B (click)='getSocketevent()'></app-component-B>
```

In component B I want to call this function:

```
getprod() {
  this.ws.getallprod().subscribe(res => {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(res);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator
  })
}
```

How to call function in component B when I get an event for this function in Component A ?

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: What's the purpose of emitting `data` how is the `child going to use it?

Comment: I want only to call function getprod() when I have emit from socket

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Component Interaction > Parent calls an @ViewChild()](https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-calls-an-viewchild)

> When the parent component class requires that kind of access,
>   **inject** the child component into the parent as a [`ViewChild`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild).

In your case it would be:

```
// A component.ts
....
@ViewChild(BComponent, {static: false})
private bComponent: BComponent;

getSocketevent() {
  this.socket.on('data', (data) => {
    // this.notify.emit(data)
    this.bComponent.getprod();
  });
}
```

[StackBlitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interaction-between-components-view-child?embed=1&file=src/app/A.component.ts)

In this case you can see that you don't really need to use an `EventEmitter`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try calling child methods from parent:

```
<app-component-B #child (click)='getSocketevent()'></app-component-B>
```

ts:

```
getSocketevent() {
    var self = this;
    this.socket.on('data', (data) => {
    this.child.getprod(); // call getprod
      this.notify.emit(data)
    });
  }
```

Comment: child ? I declaration  `child: any;` and call when I get data, but is error `core.js:9110 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getprod' of undefined`

Comment: this.child is undefined when you calling it, where do you call it?

Comment: I change It but error exist. `Property 'child' does not exist on type` How to declaration child ?

Comment: do you put ```#child``` on  app-component-B tag?

Comment: The _local variable_ approach is limited in this case because the parent-child wiring must be done entirely within the parent template. In this case the OP needs to call a function defined in the child from the parent component class (ts).